# Ceph luminous rbd map hangs forever

Tags: ceph

Running a 1 node ceph cluster, and using the ceph-client from another node. Qemu is working fine with the RBD mounting. When I try to mount a RBD block device on the ceph-client I get an indefinite hang with no output. How to diagnose whats wrong?

System is ubuntu 16.04 server, and Ceph Luminous.

```
sudo ceph tell osd.* version
{
    "version": "ceph version 12.2.2 (cf0baeeeeba3b47f9427c6c97e2144b094b7e5ba) luminous (stable)"
}


ceph -s
  cluster:
    id:     4bfcc109-e432-4ac0-ba9d-bf81243aea
    health: HEALTH_OK

  services:
    mon: 1 daemons, quorum gcmaster
    mgr: gcmaster(active)
    osd: 1 osds: 1 up, 1 in

  data:
    pools:   1 pools, 128 pgs
    objects: 1512 objects, 5879 MB
    usage:   7356 MB used, 216 GB / 223 GB avail
    pgs:     128 active+clean

rbd info gcbase
rbd image 'gcbase':
    size 512 MB in 128 objects
    order 22 (4096 kB objects)
    block_name_prefix: rbd_data.376974b0dc51
    format: 2
    features: layering, exclusive-lock, object-map, fast-diff, deep-flatten
    flags: 
    create_timestamp: Fri Dec 29 17:58:02 2017
```

This hangs forever

```
rbd map gcbase --pool rbd
```

As does this

```
rbd map typo_gcbase --pool rbd
```

dmesg shows

```
Dec 29 13:27:32 cephclient1 kernel: [85798.195468] libceph: mon0 192.168.1.55:6789 feature set mismatch, my 106b84a842a42 < server's 40106b84a842a42, missing 400000000000000
Dec 29 13:27:32 cephclient1 kernel: [85798.222070] libceph: mon0 192.168.1.55:6789 missing required protocol features
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dmesg output tells what's going on: The cluster requires a feature bit that is not supported by the libceph kernel module.

The feature bit in question is either CEPH_FEATURE_CRUSH_TUNABLES5, CEPH_FEATURE_NEW_OSDOPREPLY_ENCODING or CEPH_FEATURE_FS_FILE_LAYOUT_V2 (they are overlapping because they were introduced at the same time) which only became available on kernel 4.5, whereas Ubuntu 16.04 uses a 4.4 kernel.

A similar question (although related to CephFS) [came up on the mailing list](http://lists.ceph.com/pipermail/ceph-users-ceph.com/2017-July/019383.html) with a possible solution:

> Yes, you should be able to set your CRUSH tunables profile to hammer
>   with "ceph osd crush tunables hammer".

This will disable some features, but should make the older kernel compatible with the cluster.

Alternatively you could upgrade to a mainline kernel or to a newer OS release.

Comment: The documentation tutorial that recommends Ubuntu 16.04 should really mention this.